# For a Poset $(P,\sqsubseteq)$ and given is $A \subseteq P$ need to prove is $s=m$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, lattice-orders

There is a Poset $(P,\sqsubseteq)$ and given is $A \subseteq P$
It has both supremum $s$ and maximum $m$

Need to prove is $s=m$

---

My Work:-

Let $x \in A$  then $x \sqsubseteq m$ $\qquad$ { m is max., so it is an upperbound of $A$}

Also $x \sqsubseteq s $ $\qquad$$\qquad$ $\qquad$$\qquad$ {sup $s$ is always one of the upperbounds}

But we also know that Supremum is always the lowest of all upperbounds,

So $s \sqsubseteq m$

But I am not able to prove that $s=m$

*Does anyone have any clue for solving this.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You know that $x\sqsubseteq s$ for each $x\in A$, so in particular $m\sqsubseteq s$, since $m\in A$. You showed that $s\sqsubseteq m$, and the relation $\sqsubseteq$ is antisymmetric, so ... ?

Comment: Once again thanks Brian!

Comment: @TechJ: My pleasure!